# Expressjs with connect-mysql-session

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nowjs-sockets

I am using the connect-mysql-session module with expressjs. For **each** request to the server i get this:

```
Express server listening on port 3000 in development mode
Executing: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Sessions` (`sid` VARCHAR(255), `expires` INT, `json` TEXT, `id` INT NOT NULL auto_increment , `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
MySQL session store initialized.
Executing: SELECT * FROM `Sessions` WHERE `sid`='4SQXzLCo1O44CLMdrA1WjVVC.lecbAd5SOXHkyJfR+YEpIVJ8p9E8m79TAGGTwxnoCuo' LIMIT 1;
Executing: SELECT * FROM `Sessions` WHERE `sid`='4SQXzLCo1O44CLMdrA1WjVVC.lecbAd5SOXHkyJfR+YEpIVJ8p9E8m79TAGGTwxnoCuo' LIMIT 1;
Executing: UPDATE `Sessions` SET `sid`='4SQXzLCo1O44CLMdrA1WjVVC.lecbAd5SOXHkyJfR+YEpIVJ8p9E8m79TAGGTwxnoCuo',`expires`=1323327347,`json`='{\"lastAccess\":1323312946989,\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":14400000,\"expires\":\"2011-12-08T06:55:47.013Z\",\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"},\"status\":true,\"_csrf\":\"kzvoTUf88Nr36YR2g7w6Y9P8\"}',`id`=9,`createdAt`='2011-12-08 03:52:11',`updatedAt`='2011-12-08 03:55:47' WHERE `id`=9
Executing: SELECT * FROM `Sessions` WHERE `sid`='4SQXzLCo1O44CLMdrA1WjVVC.lecbAd5SOXHkyJfR+YEpIVJ8p9E8m79TAGGTwxnoCuo' LIMIT 1;
Executing: SELECT * FROM `Sessions` WHERE `sid`='4SQXzLCo1O44CLMdrA1WjVVC.lecbAd5SOXHkyJfR+YEpIVJ8p9E8m79TAGGTwxnoCuo' LIMIT 1;
Executing: UPDATE `Sessions` SET `sid`='4SQXzLCo1O44CLMdrA1WjVVC.lecbAd5SOXHkyJfR+YEpIVJ8p9E8m79TAGGTwxnoCuo',`expires`=1323327347,`json`='{\"lastAccess\":1323312947060,\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":14400000,\"expires\":\"2011-12-08T06:55:47.061Z\",\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"},\"status\":true,\"_csrf\":\"kzvoTUf88Nr36YR2g7w6Y9P8\"}',`id`=9,`createdAt`='2011-12-08 03:52:11',`updatedAt`='2011-12-08 03:55:47' WHERE `id`=9
Executing: SELECT * FROM `Sessions` WHERE `sid`='4SQXzLCo1O44CLMdrA1WjVVC.lecbAd5SOXHkyJfR+YEpIVJ8p9E8m79TAGGTwxnoCuo' LIMIT 1;
Executing: SELECT * FROM `Sessions` WHERE `sid`='4SQXzLCo1O44CLMdrA1WjVVC.lecbAd5SOXHkyJfR+YEpIVJ8p9E8m79TAGGTwxnoCuo' LIMIT 1;
Executing: SELECT * FROM `Sessions` WHERE `sid`='4SQXzLCo1O44CLMdrA1WjVVC.lecbAd5SOXHkyJfR+YEpIVJ8p9E8m79TAGGTwxnoCuo' LIMIT 1;
Executing: SELECT * FROM `Sessions` WHERE `sid`='4SQXzLCo1O44CLMdrA1WjVVC.lecbAd5SOXHkyJfR+YEpIVJ8p9E8m79TAGGTwxnoCuo' LIMIT 1;
Executing: SELECT * FROM `Sessions` WHERE `sid`='4SQXzLCo1O44CLMdrA1WjVVC.lecbAd5SOXHkyJfR+YEpIVJ8p9E8m79TAGGTwxnoCuo' LIMIT 1;
Executing: SELECT * FROM `Sessions` WHERE `sid`='4SQXzLCo1O44CLMdrA1WjVVC.lecbAd5SOXHkyJfR+YEpIVJ8p9E8m79TAGGTwxnoCuo' LIMIT 1;
Executing: UPDATE `Sessions` SET `sid`='4SQXzLCo1O44CLMdrA1WjVVC.lecbAd5SOXHkyJfR+YEpIVJ8p9E8m79TAGGTwxnoCuo',`expires`=1323327347,`json`='{\"lastAccess\":1323312947088,\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":14400000,\"expires\":\"2011-12-08T06:55:47.089Z\",\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"},\"status\":true,\"_csrf\":\"kzvoTUf88Nr36YR2g7w6Y9P8\"}',`id`=9,`createdAt`='2011-12-08 03:52:11',`updatedAt`='2011-12-08 03:55:47' WHERE `id`=9
Executing: UPDATE `Sessions` SET `sid`='4SQXzLCo1O44CLMdrA1WjVVC.lecbAd5SOXHkyJfR+YEpIVJ8p9E8m79TAGGTwxnoCuo',`expires`=1323327347,`json`='{\"lastAccess\":1323312947089,\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":14400000,\"expires\":\"2011-12-08T06:55:47.090Z\",\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"},\"status\":true,\"_csrf\":\"kzvoTUf88Nr36YR2g7w6Y9P8\"}',`id`=9,`createdAt`='2011-12-08 03:52:11',`updatedAt`='2011-12-08 03:55:47' WHERE `id`=9
Executing: UPDATE `Sessions` SET `sid`='4SQXzLCo1O44CLMdrA1WjVVC.lecbAd5SOXHkyJfR+YEpIVJ8p9E8m79TAGGTwxnoCuo',`expires`=1323327347,`json`='{\"lastAccess\":1323312947114,\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":14400000,\"expires\":\"2011-12-08T06:55:47.115Z\",\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"},\"status\":true,\"_csrf\":\"kzvoTUf88Nr36YR2g7w6Y9P8\"}',`id`=9,`createdAt`='2011-12-08 03:52:11',`updatedAt`='2011-12-08 03:55:47' WHERE `id`=9
Executing: SELECT * FROM `Sessions` WHERE `sid`='4SQXzLCo1O44CLMdrA1WjVVC.lecbAd5SOXHkyJfR+YEpIVJ8p9E8m79TAGGTwxnoCuo' LIMIT 1;
Executing: SELECT * FROM `Sessions` WHERE `sid`='4SQXzLCo1O44CLMdrA1WjVVC.lecbAd5SOXHkyJfR+YEpIVJ8p9E8m79TAGGTwxnoCuo' LIMIT 1;
Executing: UPDATE `Sessions` SET `sid`='4SQXzLCo1O44CLMdrA1WjVVC.lecbAd5SOXHkyJfR+YEpIVJ8p9E8m79TAGGTwxnoCuo',`expires`=1323327347,`json`='{\"lastAccess\":1323312947253,\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":14400000,\"expires\":\"2011-12-08T06:55:47.254Z\",\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"},\"status\":true,\"_csrf\":\"kzvoTUf88Nr36YR2g7w6Y9P8\"}',`id`=9,`createdAt`='2011-12-08 03:52:11',`updatedAt`='2011-12-08 03:55:47' WHERE `id`=9
```

Why is it doing this?

And i get about 8 cookies set for each request as well (connect.sid), I think it is set for each asset likje js, css and images. Why is it getting set so many times? Is it suppossed to?

heres my configuration:

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/../views');
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.register('.html', require('ejs'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(expressValidator);
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({
store: new MySQLSessionStore("test_db", "root", "root"), 
    secret: 'cat'
}));
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.csrf());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../public'));
```

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure about this, but I think you should put the static middleware more on top. The point is to have the static middleware above, since that wouldn't need sessions, cookies and other middleware, like so:

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/../views');
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.register('.html', require('ejs'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../public'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(expressValidator);
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({
store: new MySQLSessionStore("test_db", "root", "root"), 
    secret: 'cat'
}));
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.csrf());
```

Comment: Indeed that was the problem. Now it only gets executed twice, have to find out where it does that. It got rid of the cookie problem too :) I have to read up on things a bit more :/ Thanks for the reply :)